# how to setup jasmine-html in yeoman angular project

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, yeoman

I have a AngularJs project using yeoman, karma and jasmine as a test framework, every specs are running file in the console mode, but how can I view in the HTML mode. I saw the browser window appears then close right away after the tests finishes. Is the any config I should change to hold the browser window ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `karma.config` file, add in: `singleRun: false`. You can also add `autoWatch: true` to the config and it will watch your included files for changes and re-run the tests.

Edit: If you're looking for HTML based reporting, you can add this to the project

https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-html-reporter

The documentation should be pretty self-explanatory for setting that up.